# Recyclerview scrolling other layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abcd" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_interest_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_interest_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fab_submit_interest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/next_arrow" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hello guys, I am having code as shown above. I don't want to scroll the whole layout. I only want `recyclerview` to scroll. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: fix the height of `RecyclerView` or use Layout wright

Comment: didnt worked. Still the views moves up when scrolled.

Comment: You have to manage with layout weight so that your view will be visible without `scrollview` and also you have to fix the height of `RecyclerView` .

Comment: try 
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

Comment: @farhana provided the weight as 1 and made height 0 dp still it scrolls whole layout

Comment: don't use coordinate layout, I check your layout if i remove it  and using Linear layout then it is not scrolling.

Comment: @farhana tried that tpo still textview and edittext both scroll with recyclerview. Please provide your edits as ans

Answer (score 0):

Replace your layout with below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="abcd" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_interest_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_search" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_interest_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_interest_search"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fab_submit_interest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@drawable/next_arrow" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not working. It scrolls the whole layout. I just want recyclerview to scroll.